# NSDateFormatter stringFromDate, dateFromString both returning nil

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hi i'm trying to format my `NSString`. But its not working. I tried all the answers which i got in **stackoverflow**, But nothing works for me.

```
NSLog(@"log 1: %@ %@", [dealDetailsDict objectForKey:@"DealDateViewed"], [[dealDetailsDict objectForKey:@"DealDateViewed"] class]);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"log 2: %@ %@", [df stringFromDate:[dealDetailsDict objectForKey:@"DealDateViewed"]], [df dateFromString:[dealDetailsDict objectForKey:@"DealDateViewed"]]);
```

I don't know what is the problem is here, both `stringFromDate` and `dateFromString` returning `nil`. This is my `NSLog`.

```
log 1: 2013-01-09 10:02:45 +0000 __NSCFString
log 2: (null) (null)
```

I want to display date like `31-12-2010`. So i set,

```
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Here my problem started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below functionality for date format...

```
-(NSString*) Dateformate:(NSString*)str
{    
    NSDateFormatter *dfrt =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dfrt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *presentdate = [dfrt dateFromString:str];
    [dfrt setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
    NSString *fullMonth = [dfrt stringFromDate:presentdate];

    [dfrt setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
    NSString *yearStr = [dfrt stringFromDate:presentdate];
   // NSLog(@"month %@",presentdate);

    [dfrt setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [dfrt setDateFormat:@"d"];
    int date_day = [[dfrt stringFromDate:presentdate] intValue];
    NSString *suffix_string = @"|st|nd|rd|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|st|nd|rd|th|th|th|th|th|th|th|st";
    NSArray *suffixes = [suffix_string componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
    NSString *suffix = [suffixes objectAtIndex:date_day];

    NSString *fullDateFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d%@ %@",fullMonth,date_day,suffix,yearStr];

   // NSLog(@"fullDateFormat %@",fullDateFormat);

    return fullDateFormat;

}
```

Comment: @suvi : nice try, but no need to do all those lengthy stuffs, when you have many API's to serve. which are faster, flexible, tested.

Answer (score 2):

You have set date formate `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` it is for `2013-01-09 10:02:45` but your date string is `2013-01-09 10:02:45 +0000`

Either remove the zone `+0000` from your date string OR include the zone in the date format string.

Comment: Still getting nil Amit. I removed that `+0000` and tried. Still its not returning value.

Comment: +1, for helped me to sort out. Because using your help i found the answer with @suvi

Answer (score 2):

Use this one :

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
```

Then again do your required formatting as :

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

Comment: still getting `null` value

Comment: try with `[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];`

Comment: that one works, but it doesn't format. It prints the value as it is. I want to show `yyyy-MM-dd`